# Different consoles for stderr and stdout in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15

Stderr and stdout messages appear in the same console log in IntelliJ IDEA (typically in black and in red). Is there a simple way to suppress either stderr or stdout messages or redirect the two different streams to different console windows?

Answer (score 2):

How I deal with this situation is to redirect `stdout` to a file, such as `stdout.log`, when system begins.

Then Configuring IDEA's `Run/Debug Configurations - Logs` to add a log file that locate `stdout.log`

Thus, you can get `stdin` at console you just created and `stderr` at old output.

Answer (score 0):

There is this plugin called [Grep Console](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125) which allows you to use regex agasint the console outputs. Thus, it is possible to filter the outputs per your needs.

Comment: I am aware of Grep Console. However, my output to stderr does not follow a particular pattern. Unfortunately, the legacy code in question duplicates output on stderr and stdout, which makes it rather hard to read.